# This request requires authentication. Spotify API

Tags: php, api, curl, spotify

I'm trying to get all of the user's playlists from spotify, but my code returns me error 401, This request requires authentication.

I have already got the Authorisation key which is set as `$key`.
Here's my code.

```
$key='*KEYHERE*';

$userid='acorn3';

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/" . $userid . "/playlists/";
echo $url . "<br>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$header = array('Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false)
{
    echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
    echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I think I'm missing something simple here, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems ok as per the [spotify documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/). You can consider the following two to adjust your code.

1. Again double check the api key that is a valid.
2. There is an extra `/` at the end of the endpoint `playlist/`. It has a chance to cause the issue. You can try removing that `/` after playlist.